# SSL certificate issue C

Tags: c, ssl, curl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to send https requests (ssl) to an API server (Last.fm) with libcurl. When i try to send http requests it's OK but when i send https requests it isn't. After many searches in google and stack overflow i get this sample code from internet and try to execute it but it doesn’t work and show this error :

> curl_easy_perform() failed: Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates

there is the sample code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
CURLcode res;
CURL *handle = curl_easy_init();
char url[] = "https://google.com";
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_URL, url);
res=curl_easy_perform(handle);
if(res==CURLE_OK)
{
printf("OK");
}

else{
printf("curl_easy_perform() failed: %s \n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
     }

return 0;

}
```

P.S: I'm compiling with gcc from my terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by removing libcurl4-gnutls-dev and installing libcurl4-openssl-dev. If you have the same problem you just need this command :

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

This removed libcurl4-gnutls-dev automatically.